# Does prohibition of polygamy always correlate well with democracy?

Tags: religion, law, middle-east, marriage

There are only 2 countries in the Middle East where polygamy is illegal: Israel and Turkey.

There are only 2 countries in the Middle East that are true democracies: Israel and Turkey. Lebanon is controlled by Hezbollah. Egypt and the rest is recent.

Has it always been like this?

Notice that Indonesia allow polygamy for Muslims, even though it's a democracy. However, thugs often enforce power and it's still very politically incorrect. Also Arab males that engage in contract marriage sometimes get kicked out if found out (even though it's legal). So it's so politically incorrect you still can't practice it openly unless you're a person with some form of influence or control.

The idea is that certain resources, such as women, land, organ, and even "excessive happiness" are too precious that people are willing to kill to get it. Hence, most societies do not easily commercialize them. Those resources are divided proportional to political power. In democratic countries, one man one vote soon lead to one man one wife.

Some article supporting it:
http://www.salon.com/2011/07/23/monogamy_4/

> That’s not a link I’d want to make too strongly, but it has been
>   argued by historians that monogamy precedes, and then seems to go
>   along with, the emergence of democratic ideals. In the Western
>   tradition, the earliest we can trace laws about monogamy is actually
>   to Athens when the first notions of democracy began to be instituted.
>   The argument is that it’s meant to create equality among citizens so
>   that, essentially, there’ll be wives available to all Athenian men,
>   rather than having all the rich men take many wives. Although, men
>   were still allowed to have slave concubines just so as long as they
>   were non-Athenian women.
>
> You can think of it as a first kind of effort to level the playing
>   field. By saying that both the king and the peasant can only have one
>   wife each, it’s the first step toward saying that all men were created
>   equal.

Comment: Out of the 190 countries in the world, any particular reason to look at only two? And any sources to back up your claims of democracy or lack of it would be good too.

Comment: Some other democratic countries that allow polygamy (in some form or other) : India, Pakistan*, Bangladesh.

Comment: Marriage laws in India are dependent upon the religion of the subject in question. Although the Vedas and the Hindu religion itself do not outlaw polygamy, the terms under the Hindu Marriage Act has deemed polygamy to be illegal for Hindus, Jains, Buddhists, and Sikhs. Only Muslim men in India are allowed to have multiple wives, since they are governed under Sharia law. - Technically allowed but politically incorrect.

Comment: Their dominant culture doesn't allow it and only a minority of them can do it. Namely the muslim. It's like Malaysia allowing chinese to gamble.

Comment: The "minority" is about 20%.

Comment: yea. I would say from 0 to 100%, India prohibition to polygamy is 80%. Just like in US you can have polyarmory if you don't rub it out on their nose. So US is like 90% too.

Comment: What is "true democracy" in your definition?

Comment: I have to vote down; the definitions are simply too fluid, and the sample size is far too small to be useful. Is the scope the middle east, or the whole world?  I'm also confused by the notion that in Indonesia Muslims may practice polygamy, but Arabs may not.

Comment: The sample size is small. And that's precisely the point of the question. Perhaps you know bigger sample size

Comment: Turkey is a "true democracy"? srsly?

Comment: Well how much "power" is indeed on the population.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Evolutionary Psychology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_physiology) perspective

Polygamy is beneficial to

- the "desirable" men (i.e., men with power/status/wealth who can attract multiple mates) and
- "generic" women (i.e., women who cannot hope to monopolize a "desirable" man, but who can benefit from "upgrading" from being the one and only wife of a good-for-nothing bum to being the 7th wife of a rich man; this is an "upgrade" because a small share of a big fortune can be more than almost nothing).

At the very least the option (for men: taking an additional wife; for women: "upgrading") improves their negotiating power in marriage.

Note that polygamy leaves many "generic" men without a mate (and without even a hope of getting one) which puts them in a desperate position (leading to very risky behavior).

## Historical perspective

A promise of enforcing monogamy gives hope to the mass of "generic" males and thus is an extremely profitable move for any revolutionary in a polygamous society.

Observe that both Jesus and Muhammad used this move: Christianity outlawed polygamy completely, while Islam limited the number of wives to 4 and gave the promise of conquered women to the mujaheddin (jihad participants).

## Current situation

What really matters is not the legality of polygamy, but its availability. If a ["desirable" man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Mitterrand) can have an "official" mistress and no one bats an eye, then the society can be considered to be de facto polygamous.

I would expect *more* correlation between the spread of polygamy (measured by, e.g., Gini index of number of women / men or the entropy of the distribution) and the violent crime rate (which is mostly perpetrated by males), because, as I already mentioned, men without a hope for a mate tend to engage in extremely risky behavior in the off-chance of radically changing their status.

The crime rate, however, can be moderated by an oppressive government or given an outlet in military adventures, so the formula would be something like

```
glm(crime ~ polygamy + oppression + aggression)
```

Here [`glm`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/glm.html) stands for, as DVK guessed, *generalized linear model*.
In other words, if we build a regression model

```
crime ~ A + B * polygamy + C * oppression + D * aggression
```

and I conjecture

```
A > 0
B > 0
C < 0
D < 0
```

This, of course, should not imply that that there are no other possible predictors, e.g., the economic inequality as expressed as, e.g., Gini index, is probably positively correlated with crime, while general wealth negatively.

Comment: Amazing answer and analysis! Could you please expand on what glm means in-text (I'm assuming generalized linear model?)

Comment: Jesus never prohibits polygamy either

Answer (score 8):

**prohibition** of polygamy most certainly doesn't correlate with democracy.

- Polygamy was prohibited in the entire Christendom throughout Dark Ages and absolute monarchies - not exactly the best circumstances for Democracy. Same with USSR and Nazi Germany.
- On the other side of the matter, modern western democracies and USA are fairly obviously evolving into societies where polygamy will soon be legal (never mind practiced - what with French and their fabled stables of mistresses :))). I don't mean to sound like a homophobic zealot, but looking at things from legal standpoint, if you legalize marriage between ANY non-monogamic heterosexual couple (like, say, legalizing gay marriage), there is very little legal ground not to legalize any other marital arrangements.

  As a matter of fact, BDSMish subcultures practice poly* arrangements nearly openly these days.

As to whether prohibition of polygamy is **necessary** for democracy, that is less clear. I'm not aware of any research supporting or refuting this, but a fairly plausible argument can be made that any culture which has polygamy (and not polyamory) might be LESS likely to be democratic in historic context, since in a true democracy, with average male/female distribution, the non-mated males would at some point organize and vote in the prohibition (unless they are explicitly excluded from franchise).

Also, as a side note, please don't confuse democracy with things that kinda look like democracy (hint: Egypt may have had elections, doesn't necessarily make it a democracy, 95% of the power is split between the military and Muslim Brotherood. Oh, and USSR used to have those nice democratic elections all the time).

Also, don't confuse "democracy for some" with what you may think of as democracy. While franchise restriction always exists and will exist (e.g., any society would likely stop convicted killers from voting), you can for example have extremely-limited-franchise democracy like city states of Ancient Greece (VERY VERY few people were entitled to a vote, none of them women, and few of them with no access to mates).

Comment: "modern western democracies and USA are fairly obviously evolving into societies where polygamy will soon be legal" - I'm not sure where you get this and your straw man argument of legalized marriage has never been proven.  If you remove this I think your answer stands up better, otherwise it is argumentative and speculative.

Comment: @MichaelF - First of all, please refrain from personal attacks. It's not "my strawman argument of legalized marriage". My political views have nothing to do with the question, and moreover, you don't know a first thing about them and are **100% wrong** in your assumption of what they are. Second, I'm getting it from simple logic. Can you give me (putting on your lawyer hat) ONE good argument against legalizing polygamy if same sex marriage is made legal? I can't plausibly come up with a single one. The only reasons against polygamy legality wise were the SAME as against same sex marriage.

Comment: @MichaelF - moreover, that argument is pretty important to my answer, since it's the best example that a modernt democracy like OP meant can very well have legalized polygamy.

Comment: @DVK: My understanding was that Nazi Germany was planning to implement polygamy after they won the war, because they had lost so many men, and there weren't enough "Germans" to go around. Of course, it never got the that point.

Comment: @TomAu - makes perfect sense. Demographics is demographics. Based on random oral tradition I'm aware of, USSR after the war had a fairly high incidence of informal polygamy

Comment: @DVK, it's hardly a personal attack.  Legalizing Gay Marriage is not going to lead to polygamy.  If you want to believe that it's up to you, but there is no causal link between the two.  Nor have I seen any evolution towards polygamy in Western Democracies, if you have evidence show that but as I said it is out of sorts with the rest of your answer which I have no problems with.

Comment: @MichaelF - absent a legal SE where we can resolve whether i'm right or not, we are just going have to agree to disagree. I think that the point is 100% valid AND 100% germaine to my answer. You can downvote the post if you think it (or anything else) makes it a bad answer. I am open to editing the wording if you think the wording is somehow more prone to being argumentative, but I don't see a clear way to do so.

Comment: +1 for pointing this: "with average male/female distribution, the non-mated males would at some point organize and vote in the prohibition". That's the issue with. Muslims allow polygamy. But most muslims don't live in democratic countries except Indonesian and Pakistan. So perhaps perhaps, democracy, rather than religion is the more determining factor.

Comment: Just look at this map http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_status_of_polygamy and http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/krdd8/why_is_polygamy_illegal/

Comment: +1 for pointing out that christendoms are monarchs yet prohibit polygamy. However, kings in europe have tons of concubines. Also europe has a strong democracy tradition because they were once ruled by roman.

Comment: @JimThio - sorry, but the modern democracy tradition (let's say, starting with Magna Carta?) is WAY WAY younger than monogamy

Comment: Let me put it this way. Why in the earth the king of france bother prohibiting polygamy anyway? Why the king of china doesn't? Doesn't he want many girls? Doesn't his officers want many girls? So why? Maybe because the king want to appease the male populations. Why should the male populations be appeased? Because they have power nevertheless. Not exactly voting power, but rebelling power. Looks like democratic traits are stuck with mountainous geography and genes of europeans.

Comment: @JimThio - it's theologically based. King of France was a Christian king, Emperor of Chine was a king with no monogamic religion. As a good example where you're wrong, look at Russia. No polygamy once they took Christianity either, and Kievan Rus (later Novgorod excepted) wasn't exactly a hotbed of freedom, democracy and popular rebellion around 1000AD

Comment: You mean Russia allow polygamy before christianity? But then again, christianity is the spirit of greek civilization, in a sense right. They simply change the God hood. +1. I am still wrong.

Comment: +1 for showing I am wrong. That's all in the question actually. Why the down votes?

Comment: I don't do this much, but I'm actually downvoting this. It's not because I strongly disagree with the second bullet, but because it engages in the sleazy rhetorical trick of covering a very questionable assertion by saying "obviously". You do *not* get to magically shift the burden of proof off of yourself that way. Prove it, or remove it.

Comment: @T.E.D. - simple. I can randomly find tons of poly families in kink subculture that are fairly open about it. NONE of them have ever been in any trouble with the law over it in the last 20 years. If you want specific legal proof, short of 5+ Supreme Court justices saying so, nobody can prove it to you either way. I can ask around for legal opinions but they won't mean squat.

Comment: We are talking about *culture*, not transgressive subculture. The subcultures were around 150 years ago. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneida_Society

Comment: @T.E.D. - the point is, if The Man/cops wanted to harrass people over it (they way they had homosexuals 80+ years ago, or in USSR much more recently), they easily could have. It's not some deep hidden underground, they post personals ads on free personals sites. Given that civil government recognition of marriage is a very recent invention, the fact that polygamists aren't **yet** married by the Citi Hall is not the important part as far as "prohibition". Find a Wicca priest, they will happily marry your polygamist family. Nobody will arrest you for it. Q.E.D.

Comment: @DVK - No. The point is that I need documentation of this supposed gaining plural marriage movement about to take over the USA. I could make (and some have made) a plausible-sounding documentation-free argument that Sharia Law is about to take over Oklahoma. However, I believe here on this site any such bizarre assertion of imminent change should come with documentation, not just hand-waving. – T.E.D. 4 mins ago

Comment: @T.E.D. - I never said anything about "plural marriage **movement**". You are confusing legal points with political ones. I just said that there's zero legal reason to restrict marriage to monogamous coupes (as in, any objection to polygamous marriage can be rejected on same grounds as ones to same sex marriage)

Comment: @T.E.D. - looks like one of us will hopefully be conclusively proven right or wrong if [this case](http://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/2012/07/25/ister-wives-stars-sue-utah-say-polygamy-ban-is-unconstitutional/?intcmp=features) goes to Supreme court

Comment: @MichaelF, TED - [Case #1 - Striking down antipoligamy law](http://www.breitbart.com/Big-Government/2014/02/10/Polygamists-In-Utah-Rest-Easy-After-Ruling-Striking-Down-Anti-Polygamy-Law). [Case #2 - dissenting judge basically quoting the same argument I made above](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/news/3187180/posts). [Case #3 - this time a liberal judge instead of a conservative](http://mormondiscussions.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=34669). How many more judicial examples do I need to post before an apology is warranted?

Comment: This answer is precisely what I am looking for. Single males will simply vote to prohibit polygamy and hence polygamy and democracy don't mixed.

Comment: Sugar babies are already legal and that's as good as polygamy. You don't get sanctioned by the state but it's close.

Comment: @JimThio - sugar babies aren't legal - they have no legal standing as spouses in the eye of the law. E.g. if a man is married, the sugar baby (or any other gf) won't be able to inherit, etc...

Comment: It's legal in a sense that it's not a crime. People can do that openly. As for inherits, men can inherit to his biological children.

Comment: Your last paragraph is strange, as it justifies a practice that is a human rights violation and one reason why the US is way *less* democratic than it could be a likes to portray itself. Compare that eg to Germany, they even have [voting booths in prisons](https://www.lto.de/recht/nachrichten/n/bundestag-wahl-wahlrecht-wie-waehlen-haeftlinge-briefwahl-gefaengnis/) but that's of course subject to [variation](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-20447504)